# Crashlytics close event permission

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting, google-cloud-console, google-iam

In Firebase crashlytics console is it possible to give to a developer with Read-Only permission for the entire project the authorization to close crashlytics events?

I have tried the following permission for the developer:

- Error Reporting Administrator
- Error Reporting User
- Error event author
- Viewer (whole project)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks! Right now it's not possible but I'll let the team know you are interested in this feature.

Comment: Thanks. I hope it's not to late :)

Comment: +1 Please add this feature, the ability to close crash events or add a comment shouldn't be just limited to admins only. Developers were able to close events in Fabric Crashlytics.